# How to duplicate a template, populate it with data from another sheet, and rename it from a range within the other sheet without creating Template(2)?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code to create copies of a template, populate it based on the data within each row of another worksheet and rename it based on the employee in that row. However, I continue to get a sheet named Template(2).

```
Option Explicit
Sub NewSheets()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Template")
    Set sh = Sheets("Employee_Data")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    For i = 2 To Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Sheets("Template").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        ActiveSheet.Name = sh.Range("B" & i).Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("C1").Value = sh.Range("A" & i).Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("C2").Value = sh.Range("G" & i).Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("C3").Value = sh.Range("H" & i).Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("C4").Value = sh.Range("I" & i).Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("C5").Value = sh.Range("J" & i).Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("C6").Value = sh.Range("S" & i).Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("C7").Value = sh.Range("V" & i).Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("C8").Value = sh.Range("W" & i).Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("C9").Value = sh.Range("X" & i).Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("C11").Value = sh.Range("L" & i).Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("C12").Value = sh.Range("AH" & i).Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("C13").Value = sh.Range("AJ" & i).Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("C14").Value = sh.Range("AM" & i).Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("C15").Value = sh.Range("AP" & i).Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("C16").Value = sh.Range("AQ" & i).Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("H1").Value = sh.Range("F" & i).Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("H3").Value = sh.Range("K" & i).Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("N1").Value = sh.Range("C" & i).Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("N11").Value = sh.Range("N" & i).Value
    Next i
End Sub
```

I did find code which would create the multiple copies of the template and rename them as required but I cannot figure out how to write the code needed to populate the template with the data from each row for the specific employee.  That code is as follows:

```
Sub CreateSheetsFromAList()
' Example Add Worksheets with Unique Names
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Dim dic As Object, c As Range
    Dim k As Variant, tmp As String

    Set dic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set MyRange = Sheets("Employee_Data").Range("B2")
    Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))
    Sheets("Template").Visible = True

    For Each c In MyRange
        tmp = Trim(c.Value)
        If Len(tmp) > 0 Then dic(tmp) = dic(tmp) + 1
    Next c

    For Each k In dic.keys
        If Not WorksheetExists(k) Then
          Sheets("Template").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
          ActiveSheet.Name = k    ' renames the new worksheet
        End If
    Next k

    Sheets("Template").Visible = False
End Sub

Public Function WorksheetExists(ByVal WorksheetName As String) As Boolean
On Error Resume Next
  WorksheetExists = (Sheets(WorksheetName).Name <> "")
On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

I know I can always delete the extra worksheet but it would be nice if I didn't have too do that as the current project has 13 different groups for this will need to be completed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to be a little more explicit, and reduce/remove reliance on `ActiveSheet`:

```
Option Explicit

Sub NewSheets()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
    Dim sh As Worksheet, wsCopy as worksheet, v

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Template")
    Set sh = wb.Sheets("Employee_Data")

    For i = 2 To sh.Range("B" & sh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        ws.Copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
        Set wsCopy = wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count) '<<<< get a reference to the copy

        wsCopy.Name = sh.Range("B" & i).Value
        wsCopy.Range("C1").Value = sh.Range("A" & i).Value

        'EDIT: only copy value if not empty
        v = sh.Range("AJ" & i).Value
        If Len(v) > 0 Then wsCopy.Range("C13").Value = v

        '...
        'snipped for clarity
        '...
        wsCopy.Range("N11").Value = sh.Range("N" & i).Value

    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks for your response.  I tried your suggestions however it does not run correctly.  At the point that the template worksheet copy is made, it is named Template(2), Template(3), Template(4), etc. and none of the employee data is copied into the new worksheet. Again your help is appreciated.

Comment: Try unhiding it and see if anything changes.

Comment: Yes, the code works fine with no hidden worksheets!  Thank you.

Comment: Tim, your edit to skip the copy value if the source data is blank works beautifully.  Thank you for all of your help.

Comment: PS if you want to re-hide your worksheet the code should still work as long as the hidden sheet isn't the last one in the workbook.

Comment: Thank you so very much for your assistance.